# query between two dates and another data

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show houses by name between two dates (e.g. 1 year). I tried the following request, but it does not work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATA1 
WHERE facility='house' 
    AND datee BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2015-02-31'
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY datee ASC;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message? If so, please post here

Comment: LOL! i've done.

this is the solution

SELECT * 
FROM DATA1
WHERE facility= 'house'
AND (datee BETWEEN ('2014-02-01') AND ('2015-02-31') )
ORDER BY facility,datee ASC

Comment: There's no such date as 2015-02-31. February only has 28 days (29 in leap years).

Comment: @barmar not that it makes any difference in this instance!

Comment: 2014 minus 2 minus 1 equals 2011. So you need to wrap dates in inverted commas.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution!

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATA1
WHERE facility= 'house'
AND datee BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2015-02-28'
ORDER BY facility,datee ASC
```

Comment: You should explain what you fixed, not just show the code, so that readers will understand what the problem was and how yuo fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can go with these

```
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE facility= 'house' 
AND( From_date >= '2013-01-03' AND  To_date <= '2013-01-09')
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY datee ASC;
```

Comment: Hi you can go with these                                                                            SELECT * FROM DATA                                                                                  WHERE facility= 'house'                                                                     AND( From_date >= '2013-01-03 AND To_date <= '2013-01-09')GROUP BY name ORDER BY datee ASC;

Comment: Why did you get rid of `BETWEEN`? It's more readable that way than combining two conditions with `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution may be helpful for you.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATA1 
WHERE facility= 'house' 
    AND (cast(datee as date)) BETWEEN (cast('2014-02-01' as date) AND cast('2015-02-28' as date)) 
ORDER BY name, datee ASC;
```

Comment: Casting makes no difference to the result

Comment: but above query provide the correct result I think.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's slower than simply removing the casts - as per the OP's own answer

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it might help you.

```
SELECT * FROM DATA1 
WHERE facility= 'house' 
AND (dateE BETWEEN YEAR(2014-02-01) AND YEAR(2015-02-31) )
GROUP BY name ORDER BY datee ASC;
```

Comment: Dates need to be in quotes.

Comment: Yes, its only suggestion not a perfect answer. Developer should know the syntax what he doing.

Comment: If he knew the syntax, he wouldn't have needed to post the question!

Comment: And comparing dates to years makes no sense.

Comment: Your solution is equivalent to writing `AND (dateE BETWEEN 2014 and 2015)`

Comment: Yes, but you never know dates are hardcode, what if dates are dynamic and added using any variable?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're hard-coded or not. It doesn't make sense to compare a date to a year.

Comment: And even if it worked, it means you're ignoring the rest of the date. He only wants to match dates between Feb 1 2014 and Feb 31 2015. If you compare just the year, it will accept dates after February 2015.